# Суммирование значения ключа массива в цикле

Tags: массивы, php, json, sql

У меня есть некий результат sql-запроса.
Мне нужно получить в итоге json следующего вида:

```
[{
  activity_type:'Develoement',
  spent_time:[
    {user:'User1', time:'21'}, // (!) amount of time for this user and this activity
    {user:'User2', time:'2'},
  ],
  total_spent_time: 23
},{
  activity_type:'Design',
  spent_time:[
    {user:'User', time:'14'},
  ],
  total_spent_time: 14
}]
```

Вот цикл обработки sql-запроса:

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                $data[$row['activity_type']] = array('spent_time' => 
                    array('user' => (object)$row['user']));
                $data[$row['activity_type']]['spent_time']['user']->time += $row['spent_time'];

            }
```

Но в итоге я получаю:

```
[Design] => Array
    (
        [spent_time] => Array
            (
                [user] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [scalar] => John
                        [time] => 1.5  // (!) Только время последней активности, не их сумму для пользователя
                    )

            )

    )

[Developement] => Array
    (
        [spent_time] => Array
            (
                [user] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [scalar] => Nick
                        [time] => 0.3 // Только время последней активности, не их сумму для пользователя
                    )

            )

    )
```

Как суммировать активность для каждого пользователя и каждой активности в цикле?

Answer (score 1):

Если проблема в том, чтоб перевести из массива в JSON: `json_encode`.

Если вопрос в другом, уточните.

Comment: Проблема не json'e, а в том, чтобы в ключе выходного массива была сумма значений затраченного времени для каждого пользователя, к примеру, не 0,3, как в последнем случае, а, скажем, 60 или сколько там было затрачено этим пользователем во время работы на проекте.  

`$data[$row['activity_type']]['spent_time']['user']->time += $row['spent_time'];` не суммирует значение, затирает его.